# spacing in equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I need to make this formula [image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\Delta(x)=\left\{
            \begin{array}{ll}
              1  \mathrm{if} x>0\\
              -1 \mathrm{if} x<0 (1)\\
              0 \mathrm{otherwise}
            \end{array}
          \right.
```

Which it is correct just not sure how to space it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula attached in the image is not typeset right. It uses `array`, which is not the right tool in this case. `amsmath` offers you `cases` which is *exactly* for this purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Delta(x)=\begin{cases}
              1 & \text{if $x>0$}\\
              -1 & \text{if $x<0$}\\
              0 & \text{otherwise}
          \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]